Why does AT command don't work with ESP8266-01?
i have a problem with my new ESP01. I tried using AT commands with the baud rate of 115200, but don't receive OK answer. I also tried to flash it and didn't quite succeed as it's just flashing that never ends (treid for about 10 minutes).
Setup I use:

ESP8266-01
USB A to UART
TeraTerm

What I get:

When baud = 74880:



When baud = 115200:


I will really appreciate your help...

Why do you think it must response on AT commands? What firmware did you flash?

Also try this app: http://esp8266.ru/download/esp8266-utils/ESP8266_Config.zip

@MikePetrichenko it wasn't answering since I bought it, so I decided to flash it with this link firmware.

@MikePetrichenko what does this app do?

I guess the firmware is not compatible with your module or something like that. Try to flash it with default one first. Also there is a table with RX/TX pins. They are different for different firmware. Make sure your wiring is correct. The app described as a configuration tool for the module. I did not test it just found in Internet.

@MikePetrichenko tried but didn't help. Now when baud is 115200 it says MEM CHECK FAIL!!! instead of use rtc mem data

Probably incorrect memory size when flashing. Here is what I found: https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?p=29536

I solved it by flashing my ESP01 with this firmware and using CoolTerm instead of TeraTerm.
